# SFTP method to check if the given file is open

Tags: ftp, sftp, jsch, apache-commons-net

I am in the process of converting a piece of code from FTP to SFTP. In FTP, this code used to check if the given file is open or not by trying to rename the file. In library for FTP (org.apache.commons.net) this is a method which try to rename the file and return if the given file is changed or not. But in SFTP (I am using JSch library), the `rename` method returns null. My moto is to check whether the given file is open or not? Any ideas?

Below is the code in FTP:

```java
boolean renameSuccess = userSharedDrive.rename(prefixedOriginalFileName, prefixedTempRenamedFile);
```

Comment: The method is not good -- some servers could rename the file for future operations, but keep the handles valid. This is server-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSch `ChannelSftp.rename` does not return anything, it has `void` "return" type (maybe that's what you mean by null).

It throws an exception if the rename fails. So if it does not throw, the rename succeeded.

---

Another method you can try is to open the file for writing in an append mode, not writing anything to it. The opening should fail (throw an exception), if the file is opened by another process/client.

```java
sftp.put(filepath, ChannelSftp.APPEND).close()
```

This way, you do not modify (rename) the file at all.

Comment: The method seems fine, but doesn't it breaks primary purpose of error handling. We are doing a critical work when error has occurred. Error handling is supposed to handle undesired paths of execution.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: This method also seems to be server and/or client specific. In my experience with Total Commander as uploader and sshj as downloader client OpenMode.APPEND was allways ok while OpenMode.WRITE was always fail (even when no concurrent upload). Maybe some permissions involved. Anyways decided to go with the approach described by Steven (check size in some interval).

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing the check?  If you are doing a check on a file to make sure that you do not pick up a file that is in the process of being changed, then I'd recommend that you stat the file to get its modification time (SftpATTRS.getMTime) and (SftpATTRS.getSize) size.  Then wait a short period of time and stat again to make sure the modification time and size have not changed.